# How do I install gke-gcloud-auth-plugin on a Mac M1 with zsh

Tags: kubernetes, zsh, gcloud, kubectl

I try to install `gke-gcloud-auth-plugin` on a Mac M1 with zsh, following the gcloud [docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-access-for-kubectl).

The installation ran without issue and trying to re-run `gcloud components install gke-gcloud-auth-plugin` I get the `All components are up to date.` message.

However, `gke-gcloud-auth-plugin --version` returns `zsh: command not found: gke-gcloud-auth-plugin`. `kubectl`, installed the same way, works properly.

I tried to install `kubectl` using `brew`, with no more success.

Comment: I'm in the same boat, but on an Intel Mac using bash...

Comment: On the positive side, the probability to find someone to save us is higher if the issue occurs on different setups

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not sure if it is the same on macOS. Can you try the following:

```bash
export USE_GKE_GCLOUD_AUTH_PLUGIN=True
```

Then reload the Cluster with

```bash
gcloud container clusters get-credentials clustername
```

Guess it is installed but just not used.

Maybe you just need to add the directory where to find your `gke-gcloud-auth-plugin` file to your `PATH`.

Is it working when you call it wirh absolute path?

```bash
path/to/gke-gcloud-auth-plugin --version
```

to find the file use the following command:

```
sudo find / -name gke-gcloud-auth-plugin
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried but it did not work. I also assume that this could be solved using the absolute path - but this is the point: I have no idea where it is installed. I noticed that it is not the same one for all the gcloud components. `kubectl` was installed in `/usr/local/bin/kubectl` for instance.

Comment: Try: sudo find / -name  gke-gcloud-auth-plugin

Comment: Thank you ! I found it this way and I created a symbolic link to a folder my PATH. Everything works now. I accepted your answer, but how can I make your suggestion n the comments more visible?

Comment: Happy to hear it helped. I will add it in my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 40):

I had the same error and here's how I fixed it.

```
brew info google-cloud-sdk
```

which produces:

```
To add gcloud components to your PATH, add this to your profile:

  for bash users
    source "$(brew --prefix)/share/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc"

  for zsh users
    source "$(brew --prefix)/share/google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc"
    source "$(brew --prefix)/share/google-cloud-sdk/completion.zsh.inc"

  for fish users
    source "$(brew --prefix)/share/google-cloud-sdk/path.fish.inc"
```

Grab the code for your terminal and then run it (e.g., for zsh)

```
source "$(brew --prefix)/share/google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc"
```

Add the above line to your `.zshrc` profile to make sure that it is loaded every time you open a new terminal.

I had originally installed gcloud sdk with homebrew `brew install google-cloud-sdk`. At that time, I read the Caveats, which tell you how to add gcloud components to your PATH.

I installed both `kubectl` and `gke-gcloud-auth-plugin`, and neither of them could be found from the command line. I got the same error as the OP "command not found"

Comment: worked for me with a slightly different path: `/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc`

Comment: did you just copy and paste that path in .zshrc?

Comment: @samplecode3300 - yes, copy and paste the 2 lines for zsh into your .zshrc without changing them.

Comment: For me also worked custom path - "/usr/local/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc". I found it in output of "brew info google-cloud-sdk" command.

Answer (score 31):

```
gcloud components install gke-gcloud-auth-plugin
```

here we go:
[image]

Comment: This works perfectly. Cheers

Comment: Awesome thanks for your comment, much appreciated :+1